# Set spacing between plot titles in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, offset

I have a gnuplot gif file generation code:

```
set terminal pngcairo font 'DroidSerif'
set output "summary2.gif"

set xtics font ", 15"
set ytics font ", 15"
set key font ",18"
set key top right
set xlabel "Data width in bytes" font ",20"
set ylabel "Summary size" font ",20"
set title "Size comparison" font ",25"

plot  "summary2.data" using 1:4 title "BF Complete" w lp,  "summary2.data" using 1:3 title "Labeled" w lp,  "summary2.data" using 1:5 title "Complete" w lp,  "summary2.data" using 1:2 title "BF" w lap
```

The issue is that the plot titles are large so I need to add some spacing between them. How can I make it work?

[image]

Comment: Probably you should also change the global font size, because that determines the line spacing and some other positions given in character units. `set terminal pngcairo font 'DroidSerif,15'`. You'll anyway need to make some adjustments, but maybe less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `set key spacing <some number>`. Increasing the value of `<some number>` should increase the distance between titles.

Comment: Great answer.... I guess `<some number>` counts the number of characters to skip.

Comment: @many I normally use the cairolatex terminal, for which I have no clue how spacing is handled, especially when using math and other Latex formatting in the labels, so my strategy is simply "try some number until you like the result".